Can Photoshop use an SD card for a scratch disk?
On my Windows 10 computer, my c: drive is quite full and Photoshop is complaining about not enough space for the scratch disk so I bought an SD card (not an external hard drive) but it's not showing up in the scratch disk options in the Photoshop settings.
I've done some googling but all the results I've found talk about using an external hard drive for a scratch disk, not an SD card. I've tried following the directions on some of those sites, but again, the SD card just doesn't show up as a selectable drive in Photoshop. The card is formatted as exFAT which is what most of the guides say it should be (or NTFS, which I haven't tried yet). The card does show up in Windows explorer and I can read and write files to it, so I don't think the card is faulty.
I can't find anything online about SD cards for this purpose.
Does anyone here know if I should be able to use an SD card for this? And if so, how?

Most SD cards are not fast enough to support scratch disks.
If a something (a drive) does not show in Photoshop's scratch disk assignment, it simply is not sufficient for use as a scratch disk.

:( Sorry to hear this, but I can understand.
